# AngularJS Bracket Notation in Typeform data-url

Tags: angularjs, angular, url, angular-hybrid, typeform

We have an AngularJS/Angular hybrid app. In this app we are trying to do the following (using the AngularJS portion of the app):

```
<div data-url="https://brand.typeform.com/to/{{survey_id}}"></div>
```

But this doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
    Unhandled Promise rejection: JSONP request to https://admin.typeform.com/app/embed//to?jsoncallback=? failed ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: "JSONP request to https://admin.typeform.com/app/embed//to?jsoncallback=? failed"
    onerror https://embed.typeform.com/embed.js:1:142131
    wrapFn http://localhost:8080/js/vendors.d4d54ba468c86e86d307.js:240657:30
    invokeTask http://localhost:8080/js/vendors.d4d54ba468c86e86d307.js:239890:17
    runTask http://localhost:8080/js/vendors.d4d54ba468c86e86d307.js:239657:28
    invokeTask http://localhost:8080/js/vendors.d4d54ba468c86e86d307.js:239965:24
    invokeTask http://localhost:8080/js/vendors.d4d54ba468c86e86d307.js:241009:9
    globalZoneAwareCallback http://localhost:8080/js/vendors.d4d54ba468c86e86d307.js:241035:17
    d http://cdn.ravenjs.com/3.21.0/angular/raven.min.js:2:5070
 a/e.exports/</p.onerror@https://embed.typeform.com/embed.js:1:142131
wrapFn@http://localhost:8080/js/vendors.d4d54ba468c86e86d307.js:240657:30
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8080/js/vendors.d4d54ba468c86e86d307.js:239890:17
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8080/js/vendors.d4d54ba468c86e86d307.js:239657:28
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:8080/js/vendors.d4d54ba468c86e86d307.js:239965:24
invokeTask@http://localhost:8080/js/vendors.d4d54ba468c86e86d307.js:241009:9
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:8080/js/vendors.d4d54ba468c86e86d307.js:241035:17
d@http://cdn.ravenjs.com/3.21.0/angular/raven.min.js:2:5070
```

If I add the URL manually *`https://brand.typeform.com/to/123456`* it works.

How can I pass bracket notation to this element?